# How to disable submit button when no option is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 working Radio Buttons, but how can I disable the submit button when there is no option selected in the radio buttons?

```js
function getCheckedValue(radioObj) {
if(!radioObj)
    return "";
var radioLength = radioObj.length;
if(radioLength == undefined)
    if(radioObj.checked)
        return radioObj.value;
    else
        return "";
for(var i = 0; i < radioLength; i++) {
    if(radioObj[i].checked) {
        return radioObj[i].value;
    }
}
return "";
}

// set the radio button with the given value as being checked
// do nothing if there are no radio buttons
// if the given value does not exist, all the radio buttons
// are reset to unchecked
function setCheckedValue(radioObj, newValue) {
if(!radioObj)
    return;
var radioLength = radioObj.length;
if(radioLength == undefined) {
    radioObj.checked = (radioObj.value == newValue.toString());
    return;
}
for(var i = 0; i < radioLength; i++) {
    radioObj[i].checked = false;
    if(radioObj[i].value == newValue.toString()) {
        radioObj[i].checked = true;
    }
}
}
```

```css
input[type=radio] {
    -webkit-appearance: radio;
    -O-appearance: radio;
    -moz-appearance: radio;
    opacity:1;
}

#header .bottom-header.blog h1 {
    font-size: 64px;
 color: red
}

input[type=radio]:hover + label {
border: solid 1px white; padding: 5px; border-radius: 1px;
border-color : red;
color : red;
opacity:1;

}  

input[type=radio]:checked + label {
border: solid 2px white; padding: 5px; border-radius: 1px;
border-color : red;
color : red;
opacity:1;
}

input[type=text] {
font-weight:bold;
}
input[type=text]:hover {
}
input[type=email]:hover {
}
```

```html
<form name="radioExampleForm" method="get" action="" onsubmit="return false;">
<p>&nbsp;<label for="number0"><input type="radio" value="http://www.google.com" name="number"     id="number0"> Zero</label></br>
&nbsp;<label for="number1"><input type="radio" value="http://www.ebay.com" name="number" id="number1"> One</label></br>
&nbsp;<label for="number2"><input type="radio" value="http://www.gamestop.com" name="number" id="number2"> Two</label></br>
</p>
<input type="button" onclick="window.open(getCheckedValue(document.forms['radioExampleForm'].elements['number']), '_blank');" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `disabled` attribute to the button HTML
and add this code to listen to changes in the radio buttons. on change enable the submit button.

I added this code

```
var radioBtns = document.radioExampleForm.number;
for (var i = 0; i < radioBtns.length; i++) {
    radioBtns[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
      document.getElementById("submitBtn").disabled = false;
    });
}
```

```js
var radioBtns = document.radioExampleForm.number;
for (var i = 0; i < radioBtns.length; i++) {
    radioBtns[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
      document.getElementById("submitBtn").disabled = false;
    });
}
function getCheckedValue(radioObj) {
if(!radioObj)
    return "";
var radioLength = radioObj.length;
if(radioLength == undefined)
    if(radioObj.checked)
        return radioObj.value;
    else
        return "";
for(var i = 0; i < radioLength; i++) {
    if(radioObj[i].checked) {
        return radioObj[i].value;
    }
}
return "";
}

// set the radio button with the given value as being checked
// do nothing if there are no radio buttons
// if the given value does not exist, all the radio buttons
// are reset to unchecked
function setCheckedValue(radioObj, newValue) {
if(!radioObj)
    return;
var radioLength = radioObj.length;
if(radioLength == undefined) {
    radioObj.checked = (radioObj.value == newValue.toString());
    return;
}
for(var i = 0; i < radioLength; i++) {
    radioObj[i].checked = false;
    if(radioObj[i].value == newValue.toString()) {
        radioObj[i].checked = true;
    }
}
}
```

```css
input[type=radio] {
    -webkit-appearance: radio;
    -O-appearance: radio;
    -moz-appearance: radio;
    opacity:1;
}

#header .bottom-header.blog h1 {
    font-size: 64px;
 color: red
}

input[type=radio]:hover + label {
border: solid 1px white; padding: 5px; border-radius: 1px;
border-color : red;
color : red;
opacity:1;

}  

input[type=radio]:checked + label {
border: solid 2px white; padding: 5px; border-radius: 1px;
border-color : red;
color : red;
opacity:1;
}

input[type=text] {
font-weight:bold;
}
input[type=text]:hover {
}
input[type=email]:hover {
}
```

```html
<form name="radioExampleForm" method="get" action="" onsubmit="return false;">
<p>&nbsp;<label for="number0"><input type="radio" value="http://www.google.com" name="number"     id="number0"> Zero</label></br>
&nbsp;<label for="number1"><input type="radio" value="http://www.ebay.com" name="number" id="number1"> One</label></br>
&nbsp;<label for="number2"><input type="radio" value="http://www.gamestop.com" name="number" id="number2"> Two</label></br>
</p>
<input type="button" id="submitBtn" disabled onclick="window.open(getCheckedValue(document.forms['radioExampleForm'].elements['number']), '_blank');" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: not working below #Lonnie Best addded the code which is working

Comment: I don't know why it's not working for you, make sure you add the button id and the disable attribute to the button html

Answer (score 1):

Pure JS: Try this

```js
function handleChange1(){
 document.getElementById("test").disabled = false;;
}
```

```html
<form name="radioExampleForm" method="get" action="" onsubmit="return false;">
<p>&nbsp;<label for="number0"><input type="radio" onchange="handleChange1()" value="http://www.google.com" name="number"     id="number0"> Zero</label></br>
&nbsp;<label for="number1"><input type="radio" onchange="handleChange1()" value="http://www.ebay.com" name="number" id="number1"> One</label></br>
&nbsp;<label for="number2"><input type="radio" onchange="handleChange1()" value="http://www.gamestop.com" name="number" id="number2"> Two</label></br>
</p>
<input id ="test"  type="button" onclick="window.open(getCheckedValue(document.forms['radioExampleForm'].elements['number']), '_blank');" value="Submit" disabled>
</form>
```

Comment: dunno if it's really JS compliant but works.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to accomplish disabling the submit button, is to simply add a `disabled` attribute directly into the html of the submit button input. This way, the submit button is disable before it is even rendered to the screen:

```
<input disabled id="submitBtn" type="button" onclick="window.open(getCheckedValue(document.forms['radioExampleForm'].elements['number']), '_blank');" value="Submit">
```

After this, you can add an click-event listener to the document, so that, "when a radio-item is selected" (that has the name of `number`) you can immediately remove that `disabled` attribute from the submit button input, and therefore make it re-enabled:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function enableSubmit(event)
{
    let submitBtn = document.getElementById("submitBtn");
    if (event.target.type === "radio" && event.target.name === "number")
    {
        submitBtn.removeAttribute("disabled");
        // Now, we can also remove this vary event listener:
        document.removeEventListener('click', enableSubmit);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function enableSubmitBtn(){
  document.getElementById("submitBtn").disabled = false;
}

function getCheckedValue(radioObj) {
if(!radioObj)
    return "";
var radioLength = radioObj.length;
if(radioLength == undefined)
    if(radioObj.checked)
        return radioObj.value;
    else
        return "";
for(var i = 0; i < radioLength; i++) {
    if(radioObj[i].checked) {
        return radioObj[i].value;
    }
}
return "";
}

// set the radio button with the given value as being checked
// do nothing if there are no radio buttons
// if the given value does not exist, all the radio buttons
// are reset to unchecked
function setCheckedValue(radioObj, newValue) {
console.log('call');
if(!radioObj)
    return;
var radioLength = radioObj.length;
if(radioLength == undefined) {
    radioObj.checked = (radioObj.value == newValue.toString());
    return;
}
for(var i = 0; i < radioLength; i++) {
    radioObj[i].checked = false;
    if(radioObj[i].value == newValue.toString()) {
        radioObj[i].checked = true;
    }
}
}
```

```css
input[type=radio] {
    -webkit-appearance: radio;
    -O-appearance: radio;
    -moz-appearance: radio;
    opacity:1;
}

#header .bottom-header.blog h1 {
    font-size: 64px;
 color: red
}

input[type=radio]:hover + label {
border: solid 1px white; padding: 5px; border-radius: 1px;
border-color : red;
color : red;
opacity:1;

}  

input[type=radio]:checked + label {
border: solid 2px white; padding: 5px; border-radius: 1px;
border-color : red;
color : red;
opacity:1;
}

input[type=text] {
font-weight:bold;
}
input[type=text]:hover {
}
input[type=email]:hover {
}
```

```html
<form name="radioExampleForm" method="get" action="" onsubmit="return false;">
<p>&nbsp;<label for="number0" onclick="enableSubmitBtn()"><input type="radio" value="http://www.google.com" name="number" id="number0"> Zero</label></br>
&nbsp;<label for="number1" onclick="enableSubmitBtn()"><input type="radio" value="http://www.ebay.com" name="number" id="number1"> One</label></br>
&nbsp;<label for="number2" onclick="enableSubmitBtn()"><input type="radio" value="http://www.gamestop.com" name="number" id="number2"> Two</label></br>
</p>
<input type="button" id="submitBtn" disabled="true" onclick="window.open(getCheckedValue(document.forms['radioExampleForm'].elements['number']), '_blank');" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: not working above #Lonnie Best addded the code which is working